# bind horse A to horse B's skeleton

Tags: rigging, armature, vertex-weights

I have two different horses with their animations.I want to have horse A to use horse B's animations. So I am trying to bind horse A to horse B's skeleton and import back to UE5.

I am not familiar with Blender. In Blender I have tried deleting horse A's armature and B's mesh, Right now the mesh and armature are separate. But I try to move the armature inside the horse and do *armature deform with automatic weights*. Then I export using send to unreal addon, but the imported horse I got in unreal is not playing animations. The skeleton tree is gray with the prompt message " this bone exists only on the skeleton but not on the current mesh".

Could you give me some help?

Comment: Have you tried to give to armature A's bones the exact same names as aramture B's bones?

Comment: I have deleted horse A's armature. Do you suggest me to change names before deletion? The two skeletons have different number of bones. armature deform seems to have no effect. If I go to pose mode and rotate the bone, the mesh won't move accordingly. It looks like the mesh and the bones are irrelevant or not connected. I am not familiar with the terminology of blender.